# Вывод дефолтной картинки если пользователь не установил свою

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Здравстуйте! Прошу помочь с написанием SQL запроса.

Есть для каждого пользователя в начале после регистрации дефолтная картинка: (`../media/images/users/default.png`). Она записана в ячейку базы `userImage`. После ввода email в этой форме, надо чтобы в `src` у `img` появился этот путь, а в поле имя выводился никнейм из той же строки. Я без понятия как написать такой запрос, что бы вывести информацию. Сам запрос такой: `SELECT id FROM Users WHERE email = $_POST['email']` и вот после этого надо найти в этой строке `name` и `userImage` и вывести их так:

```html
<div>
<figure>
<img src="тут должен быть источник"/>
<figcaption>А тут имя</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

Comment: `надо найти в этой строке` в какой такой строке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно по умолчанию делать поле userImage пустым null

после получения результата выборки кстати запрос нужно подредактировать, * вместо id

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email =".$_POST['email']); //вообще не хорошо - потенция для sql - инъекции, лучше бы PDO использовать
$src = ($result['userImage']) ? $result['userImage'] : '/path/to/default.img';

<div>
<figure>
<img src="<?=$src?>"/>
<figcaption><?=$result['name']?></figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

Comment: А в BLOB'e это не оч вариант?

Comment: Это конечно. Но раздуем размер базы, а потом тяжко будет дергать Select. Как по мне лучше просто ссылки, а то и просто имена файлов держать там.